# Error create VM in Glance in centos-7

Tags: virtual-machines, centos7, openstack, openstack-glance

I'm facing an issue while installing a VM in Glance-Openstack. Here it is

[root@parkst ~(keystone)]# virt-install \

```
--name centos7 \ --ram 2048 \ --disk path=/var/kvm/images/centos7.img,format=qcow2 \ --vcpus 2 \ --os-type linux \ --os-variant rhel7 \ --graphics none \ --console pty,target_type=serial \ --location '/home/sayan/Desktop/CentOS-6.6-x86_64-bin-DVD2.iso' \ --extra-args 'console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
```

Starting install... Retrieving file .treeinfo... | 728 B 00:00
ERROR Couldn't acquire file /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.WtfSht/images/pxeboot/vmlinuz: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.WtfSht/images/pxeboot/vmlinuz" Domain installation does not appear to have been successful. If it was, you can restart your domain by running: virsh --connect qemu:///system start centos7 otherwise, please restart your installation.

please help me from this situation

One more issue i have, When i Source the "source ~/keystonerc", I'm unable to get out from here. Please tell me is there any option to come out from this situation without installing the VM. I tried every option to release myself from ~keystonerc ./bash shell. But i failed in it. please tell me the way.